# develop an Ajax client like google maps with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, gwt

Would it be possible (and recommendable) to develop an Ajax map client like [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) with [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/overview.html)? Would it be easier to use something like JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it would be possible with GWT and no I don't think it would be easier to use jquery, I think it would be much harder.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat depends on your programming skills. For me it would be much easier with GWT, because I don't talk Javascript and with GWT I can do everything in Java.

Of course, on the other hand, a Javascript-Guru might achieve the same with JQuery in a much shorter time period.

Comment: I prefer Java too. What I want do know was: would it be possible to avoid JavaScript coding with GWT in this case. And the answer seems to be "yes".

Comment: Yep, GWT was born to do things like this. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the Google Maps content, you can always plug Google Maps into GWT with [Google API Libraries for Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted).

Comment: Why is it under the deprecated section of the gwt-google-api?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there is at least one library written in GWT that emulates what Google Maps does.  Check out

http://www.maryanovsky.com/sasha/maps/

Comment: Sasha Maps license is either free for non commercial or a paid license.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an existing open source Javascript map client like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), rather than reinventing the wheel?